# WAMP / apache requests not responding

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, wamp

http://localhost isn't responding for extended periods of time (stopped waiting after 10 minutes), nor are any of my vhosts.

I've tried looking at the error logs and I don't see any entries since 2010 and I use my vhosts daily.  As far as I know, I haven't changed any apache settings, everything looks fine with the hosts file, httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf.  In fact, there has been no modification in these folders in months.  It's possible an automatic update or a recent update to LogMeIn could have done something elsewhere in the windows environment.

I'm restarting apache via:

```
MyPath\Apache2.2.17\bin\httpd.exe -k restart
```

and seeing no errors in the command console and as I mentioned, the apache logs are not updating

Two questions:
1) Any idea why the logs aren't populating?
2) What steps could I use to troubleshoot this issue?

UPDATE:

I found the apache logs were populating, just under wamp/logs and not the log files under the apache folder.  Every time I restart apache I get a few thousand of these:

[Sat May 05 13:30:26 2012] [error] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : Child 9532: Encountered too many errors accepting client connections. Possible causes: dynamic address renewal, or incompatible VPN or firewall software. Try using the Win32DisableAcceptEx directive.

I tried adding

```
Win32DisableAcceptEx
```

to my httpd.conf file and the errors have changed but they are too numerous to list.  What could have changed to have caused this?

Answer (score 0):

It's `wsock32.dll` under `system32` folder which is corrupt, probably by some rootkit or application, try booting machine with Windows CD and replace the file, the issue will get solved

Comment: Can you elaborate on how `wsock32.dll` could be causing this problem?

Comment: I never found a resolution to this problem and have since reinstalled my os and everything is working fine.  Apologies to anyone having this problem later, I never found a working solution and am no longer able to test suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

check your

> c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

file. check there is a line without " # ".

> 127.0.0.1 localhost

If not present, update and try again.